# firestore permission denied with security rule all allowed, even after Firebase signin succeeded

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This issue happens for years but it's still bothering developers.

> [Error: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.]

My firestore rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if true;
        }
    }
}
```

Firebase SigninWithEmailAndPassword succeeds, but when `firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).get()`
it displays this error.

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^18.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^18.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^18.5.0",
```

note: it happens both on iOS and Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had the same issue and for me it was because I enabled the 'App Check' feature on Firebase without properly configuring it. If you enforce 'App Check' on Cloud Firebase without properly setting up the reCAPTCHAP code in your project it will reject unverified client request.  It is looking for a token and it will reject clients if enforced. https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider } from "firebase/app-check";

const app = initializeApp({
  // Your Firebase configuration object.
});

// Create a ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider instance using your reCAPTCHA Enterprise
// site key and pass it to initializeAppCheck().
const appCheck = initializeAppCheck(app, {
  provider: new ReCaptchaEnterpriseProvider(/* reCAPTCHA Enterprise site key */),
  isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true // Set to true to allow auto-refresh.
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I suppose the Enterprise reCAPTCHA site key is for a website platform. If it is, what domain name should I use? If it is not, please clarify. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think it should match authDomain in your initialization config of Firebase in your project.

Comment: Thanks. So, for those who might be wondering what authDomain is. (1) you need to add web as an application to your Firebase project. (2) get the the generated authDomain. The following can help you find it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52500573/